# JPA: how do I persist a String into a database field, type MYSQL Text

Tags: java, mysql, orm, jpa

The requirement is that the user can write an article, therefore I choose type `Text` for the `content` field inside mysql database. How can I convert `Java String` into `MySQL Text`

Here you go `Jim Tough`

```
@Entity
public class Article implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Long userId;

    private String title;

    private String content;

    private Integer vote;

    //Constructors, setters, getters, equals and hashcode
}
```

In my MYSQL database, `content` is type `Text`.  I was hoping that there would be something like this `java.sql.Text`, since `java.sql.Blob` is an actual type, but sadly, that does not exist

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Since you're using JPA, use the `Lob` annotation (and optionally the `Column` annotation). Here is what the JPA specification says about it:

> #### 9.1.19 Lob Annotation
>
> A `Lob` annotation specifies that a
>   persistent property or field should be
>   persisted as a large object to a
>   database-supported large object type.
>   Portable applications should use the
>   `Lob` annotation when mapping to a
>   database Lob type. The Lob annotation
>   may be used in conjunction with the
>   `Basic` annotation. A Lob may be
>   either a binary or character type. The
>   Lob type is inferred from the type of
>   the persistent field or property, and
>   except for string and character-based
>   types defaults to Blob.

So declare something like this:

```
@Lob 
@Column(name="CONTENT", length=512)
private String content;
```

#### References

- JPA 1.0 specification:

  - Section 9.1.19 "Lob Annotation"

Comment: On Hibernate JPA MYSQL, using `@Lob` plus `@Column` annotation on a String field gives "wrong column type, expected longtext but column type is text". But the problem is solved when I used `@Column(columnDefinition = "text")`

Comment: What's the sense in combining `@Lob` and `@Column(length=512)`? Why not just be happy with `@Lob`? Both make no difference when using Hibernate JPA MySQL. Both result in the MySQL field type `longtext`.

Comment: I had a binary column type, and the `@Lob` annotation didn't work for me. However, `@Column(length=8192)` worked great and solved my problem.

Answer (score 148):

With `@Lob` I always end up with a `LONGTEXT`in MySQL.

To get `TEXT` I declare it that way (JPA 2.0):

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String text
```

Find this better, because I can directly choose which Text-Type the column will have in database.

For `columnDefinition` it is also good to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078681/what-properties-does-column-columndefinition-make-redundant).

EDIT: Please pay attention to Adam Siemions [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868096/jpa-how-do-i-persist-a-string-into-a-database-field-type-mysql-text/22650941#comment39994750_22650941) and check the database engine you are using, before applying `columnDefinition = "TEXT"`.

Comment: This is not a good solution, as TEXT data column is not available in all the databases engines, e.g. HSQLDB, details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213782/hibernate-postgresql-hsqldb-text-column-incompatibility-problem

Comment: this is what i wanted because it is what is available in all production databases, and does not have the issue with "longtext" when i don't want it.

Answer (score 43):

for mysql 'text':

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String description;
```

for mysql 'longtext':

```
@Lob
private String description;
```