# Setting compatibility mode for spring embedded-database

Tags: java, spring, hsqldb, embedded-database

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5007966/1479414) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12290408/1479414) answer `hsqldb` datasource can be changed to work with enabled MySQL compatibility mode using this connection URL:
`jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;sql.syntax_mys=true`

My question is more specific: how to turn this mode when using Spring's embedded-database? So it's just:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL" >
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

I have no idea where to place in this configuration compatibility mode parameters. Any ideas?

Comment: In this case you have to create data source by yourself.

Comment: @SlavaSemushin This is not about spring embedded database. I'm interested to keep using `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded` stuff

Comment: You cannot use the namespace you will have to create the datasource yourself and you cannot use the embedded classes anymore. Unless you construct your own `EmbeddedDatabaseConfigurer` and configure everything manually instead of using the namespace. But in the end you are still using a `DataSource` a `SimpleDriverDataSource` to be exact (which is something you shouldn't be using for Production but only testing/prototyping!).

Comment: You can't set compatible mode through the jdbc:embedded-database configuration. Check out this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171743/does-spring-embedded-database-support-different-sql-dialects