# JPA Entity data type for MySQL5 Text

Tags: mysql, jpa

MaxOSX10.7.5
MySQL5
JDK6
JPA2

I've just started JPA and have a entity class. It has a String member mapping to MySQL text type like below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Device")
public class Device {

    @Column(name="notes")
    public String notes; 

}
```

MySQL definition:

```
`notes` text CHARACTER SET utf8
```

When I try to do unit test, I am getting error:

... for column notes. Found: text, expected: longtext

I added @Lob annotation but it didn't work. And I put length property like length=2000|10000|20000 but no luck.
In addition @Lob + length property but same.

How can I solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Include the SQL and the full error.

Comment: It sounds like a bug : https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3440

Comment: @williome Thanks, it is helpful to me. I hope it would be fixed soon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA: how do I persist a String into a database field, type MYSQL Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868096/jpa-how-do-i-persist-a-string-into-a-database-field-type-mysql-text)