# What properties does @Column columnDefinition make redundant?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I often specify my `@Column` annotations like this:

```
@Column(columnDefinition="character varying (100) not null",length=100,nullable=false)
```

As you can see I specify `length` and `nullable` even though the `columnDefinition` already specifies those. That's because I don't know where/when these values are used exactly.

So, when specifying `columnDefinition`, what other properties of `@Column` are made redundant?

If it matters, I use Hibernate and PostgreSQL

Comment: if you are going to specify it the exact column will be created in your database otherwise it will be created as default as per database

Comment: I should add that I no longer use this property at all, and prefer to do my own DDL.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

**My Answer: All of the following should be overridden (i.e. describe them all within `columndefinition`, if appropriate):**

- `length`
- `precision`
- `scale`
- `nullable`
- `unique`

i.e. the column DDL will consist of: `name` + `columndefinition` *and nothing else*.

Rationale follows.

---

1. Annotation containing the word "Column" or "Table" is purely physical - properties *only* used to control DDL/DML against database.
2. Other annotation purely logical - properties used in-memory in java to control JPA processing.
3. That's why sometimes it appears the optionality/nullability is set twice - once via `@Basic(...,optional=true)` and once via `@Column(...,nullable=true)`.  Former says attribute/association can be null in the JPA object model (in-memory), at flush time; latter says DB column can be null.  Usually you'd want them set the same - *but not always*, depending on how the DB tables are setup and reused.

In your example, length and nullable properties are overridden and redundant.

---

> ***So, when specifying columnDefinition, what other properties of @Column are made redundant?***

1. In JPA Spec & javadoc:

   - `columnDefinition` definition:
     **The SQL fragment that is used when generating the DDL for the column.**
   - `columnDefinition` default:
     **Generated SQL to create a column of the inferred type.**
   - The following examples are provided:

     ```
     @Column(name="DESC", columnDefinition="CLOB NOT NULL", table="EMP_DETAIL")
     @Column(name="EMP_PIC", columnDefinition="BLOB NOT NULL")
     ```
   - And, err..., that's it really.  :-$  ?!

   **Does columnDefinition override other properties provided in the same annotation?**

   The javadoc and JPA spec don't explicity address this - spec's not giving great protection. To be 100% sure, test with your chosen implementation.
2. The following can be safely implied from examples provided in the JPA spec

   - **`name` & `table` can be used in conjunction with `columnDefinition`, neither are overridden**
   - **`nullable` is overridden/made redundant by `columnDefinition`**
3. The following can be fairly safely implied from  the "logic of the situation" (did I just say that?? :-P ):

   - **`length`, `precision`, `scale` are overridden/made redundant by the `columnDefinition` - they are integral to the type**
   - **`insertable` and `updateable` are provided separately and never included in `columnDefinition`, because they control SQL generation in-memory, before it is emmitted to the database.**
4. That leaves just the "`unique`" property.  It's similar to nullable -  extends/qualifies the type definition, so should be treated integral to type definition.  i.e. should be overridden.

---

**Test My Answer**
For columns "A" & "B", respectively:

```
  @Column(name="...", table="...", insertable=true, updateable=false,
          columndefinition="NUMBER(5,2) NOT NULL UNIQUE"

  @Column(name="...", table="...", insertable=false, updateable=true,
          columndefinition="NVARCHAR2(100) NULL"
```

- confirm generated table has correct type/nullability/uniqueness
- optionally, do JPA insert & update: former should include column A, latter column B

Comment: Does this annotation work when the column already exists in the DB with varchar(100) and I want to make it as varchar(255) ?

Answer (score 10):

**columnDefinition** will override the sql DDL generated by hibernate for this particular column, it is non portable and depends on what database you are using. You can use it to specify nullable, length, precision, scale... ect.

Comment: I know what it does, and that it's not portable, but is the DDL generation the only place where the other properties (`length`, `nullable`, etc.) are normally used?

Comment: According to the source code of `javax.persistence.Column`, properties: `unique`, `nullable`, `columnDefinition`, `length`, `precision`, `scale` are only used to DDL generation, properties: `name`, `table` are used to specify column mapping, and properties: `insertable`, `updatable` are used to specify whether the column is included in SQL INSERT/UPDATE statements generated by the persistence provider.