# How to use Enum members in a Hibernate @Entity class?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, enums

I have the following class:

```
@Entity
class User
{
   @Id @GeneratedValue
   private long id;

   private Language lang; //Language is an Enum of all languages

   private Role role; //Role is an enum of user roles like admin, super-admin, etc

}
```

My questions are:

1) How should I design the database column to work with the enum types? Should I use varchar, or any other type? (I'm using MySQL)

2) Will this class work out of the box, or do I need to do anything extra to make it work with Enums? I need to be able to both read, and write the enum values (e.g user can change his language)

Comment: @Enum annotation - you can specify if you want to store enum as string or as integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `VARCHAR` type and in the `@Entity` class mark the enum members with the `@Enumerated` and the `@Column` annotations (to point to which database table column will the enum member binded).

For example:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "enum('BULGARIA','UNITED KINGDOM')")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Language lang;

@Column(columnDefinition = "enum('ADMIN','USER')")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Role role;
```

Comment: Will this work with existing database columns, or will it try to create them? The definition might get a bit long with all the languages, is there any other way?

Comment: I already have the database column made btw. Do I still need to specify @ColumnDef ?

Comment: Checkout this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078681/what-properties-does-column-columndefinition-make-redundant

Comment: I was able to get this to work just fine, using a varchar column and just using `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`. Didn't need the `@Column` part.