# How to Specify SQL real-type on Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

We have an SQL Table with a column of type "real" that we are tying to read from using Hibernate. When we try to read from that we are expecting a type float but are getting this error:

```
found [real (Types#REAL)], but expecting [float (Types#FLOAT)]
```

Currently we do not have this field annotated with anything else than this?

```
@Column(name = "BatteryVoltage")
private float batteryVoltage;
```

However, I expect we might need to use either `percision` and/or `scale`.  Does hibernate have a solution for this or is it necessary to alter table configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the Hibernate "Validate" step was failing to map the float type to a real type. I don't believe there was actually a run-time error. The solution, as this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078681/what-properties-does-column-columndefinition-make-redundant) goes into, is to use the `@Column(columnDefinition=...` annotation.

This solution worked for us:

```
@Column(name = "BatteryVoltage", columnDefinition = "real")
private float batteryVoltage;
```